# Вырезать содержимое png и создать новую картинку

Tags: c++, png

Читаю содержимое png файла с помощью stb_image.h сохраняю с помощью stb_image_write.

```
#define CHANNEL_NUM 4
int width, height, bpp;
string myImage = "test.png";
unsigned char *data = stbi_load(pathImage.c_str(), &width, &height, &bpp, STBI_rgb_alpha);
if (!data)
    {
        std::cout << "No File." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
```

создаю новою так

```
std::string out = "out.png";
stbi_write_png(out.c_str(), width, height, CHANNEL_NUM, data, width*CHANNEL_NUM);
stbi_image_free(data);
```

размер загружаймой картинки 302х311, как мне вырезать нужной фрагмент по координатам, к примеру таким:

```
[w: 37][h: 77][x: 0][y: 156]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`width, height` заменяете на желаемую ширину и высоту.

Начальные координаты запихиваете в тот аргумент где `data`, вот так `data + CHANNEL_NUM * (x + y * width)`.

Comment: @user7860670 Не, обратите внимание на последний параметр - `width*CHANNEL_NUM` - это разница между адресами соседних строк.